# Derivative of a product respect a vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

Studying *Portfolio Theory* I have had a doubt about a derivative of a function that appears in the book I'm following.

If I have the function,

$$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{w},\lambda)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{w}+\lambda\mathbf{w}\mathbf{\mu}$$

where, $\mathbf{w},\mathbf{\mu}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a *n-square* symmetric matrix (with real entries). Then the partial derivative (according with the book) is,

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\mathbf{w}}=\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{w}+\lambda\mathbf{\mu}$$
I understand the second term ($\lambda\mathbf{\mu}$), but I don't know why $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\mathbf{w}}=\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{w}$. I have searched about derivatives of vectors but maybe I'm searching in the wrong place, because I haven't found anything useful.

---

Thanks in advance. I just want to understand why is that equality true and if there's a formal justification (or a definition that I don't know).

Comment: The gradient of ${\mathcal L}=(w^T\Sigma w+\lambda\mu^Tw)$ is $$\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial w}=\frac{1}{2}\big(\Sigma+\Sigma^T\big)w+\lambda\mu$$ If the matrix is symmetric, then you will recover the book's result.

Comment: Oops! Omit the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in my previous comment. Now if the matrix is symmetric, either the book's answer is wrong or you've written the function incorrectly in your post.

Comment: @greg Oh, thanks. I've just noticed that I omit some details. I've edited the question; however, I can't get why that's the gradient of $\mathcal{L}$. Maybe is a stupid question, but I'm a little confused and I don't have someone else to ask. Could you explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a scalar function of a matrix and two vectors
$$\phi = a^TMb$$
Since the transpose operation does not affect scalar values we can write this in a number of different forms 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi
 &= (a^TMb)^T = b^TM^Ta \cr
 &= (Mb)^Ta = (M^Ta)^Tb \cr
}$$
Let's find the gradient with respect to each vector. Start by finding the differential
$$\eqalign{\phi &= (Mb)^T\,da + (M^Ta)^T\,db \cr}$$
Holding $b$ constant makes $db=0$ and we obtain
$$\eqalign{
 d\phi &= (Mb)^T\,da \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial a} &= Mb \cr
}$$
Similarly, holding $a$ constant yields
$$\eqalign{
 d\phi &= (M^Ta)^T\,db \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial b} &= M^Ta \cr
}$$
If $(a=b=w)$ then there is only one vector, but we have to treat each occurrence independently.  Using the above results we have
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial w} &= Mw + M^Tw \cr
}$$
And if $M^T=M$ then we can simplify this to 
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial w} &= 2Mw \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank's a lot. Perfectly explained.